# Python: Error when running two different .py files

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, scheduled-tasks, python-multiprocessing

I'm trying to schedule two different .py files (with multi processing) to run every day at a certain intervals. I was able to successfully run the files concurrently without the schedule module

but when I try to schedule the code, I'm getting two different errors one is PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access denied and the other is the files were running sequentially (not at the same time)

here's the code that I used:
This codes runs the script sequentially

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import time
import schedule

def one(): 
   import International
def two():
   time.sleep(2)
   import National

if __name__ == '__main__':
  Process(target=schedule.every().days.at("16:17").do(one)).start()       
  Process(target=schedule.every().days.at("16:17").do(two)).start()

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

This one throws: PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access denied

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import time
import schedule

def both_at_once():
  def one(): 
    import International
  def two():
    import National

  if __name__ == '__main__':
    Process(target=one).start()
    Process(target=two).start()

schedule.every().days.at("16:33").do(both_at_once)

while True:
   schedule.run_pending()
   time.sleep(1)
```

Kindly let me know where I'm going wrong.

Comment: You have a number of serious problems here.  The whole concept is flawed.  One BIG problem is that `import` only runs the file the first time it is imported.  What you need to do is define a function inside each of those modules that does what you need, then do the imports globally, and call `International.run()`.  And remember that, when you start a multiprocess, it runs your WHOLE main again.  The `if __name__` thing needs to protect ALL of your one-time code.  I'll try to post an alternative below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the kind of thing you need.  The `__main__` code needs to file the schedule and then run the schedule.  The functions it calls would then do the multiprocessing step.

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import time
import schedule
import International
import National

def one(): 
    Process(target=National.run).start()
def two():
    Process(target=International.run).start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    schedule.every().days.at("16:17").do(one)
    schedule.every().days.at("16:17").do(two)
    while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
        time.sleep(1)
```

However, you might consider if this would be better implemented with something like `cron`.